MAUI Back Button not working more than 1 level deep
I'm working with App.Shell and for the most part that's perfect for this app.  Occasionally I want to drill a little deeper in the stack of pages, but when I go more than 1 level deep the back button stops working!
So from Page1 to Page2 , I can click <- Back and it works as expected.
When I go from Page2 to Page3 the Back button won't work.
Also the same goes for the Android Back Button, works on page2 but not page 3.
For testing; I have a 3 pages (Page1, Page2, Page3) and 3 viewmodels.  I have tried variations of the navigation code, Shell Navigation / Page Navigation / with / without forward slashes etc.
All are registered in Maui.Program.cs
 builder.Services.AddTransient<Page1>();
 ...
 builder.Services.AddTransient<ViewModel3>();

I have 3 routes in the App.Shell constructor
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page1), typeof(Page1));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page2), typeof(Page2));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page3), typeof(Page3));
}

the pages have a button for navigation
  <Button Command="{Binding GoToPage2Command}" Text="Go to Two"/>
    

and in the ViewModel a RelayCommand
public partial class ViewModel1
{
    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task GoToPage2()
    {
        //BACK BUTTON WORKS
        //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Page2");

        //BACK BUTTON WORKS
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(new ViewModel2()));
    }
}

public partial class ViewModel2
{
    [RelayCommand]
    public async void GoToPage3()
    {
        //BACK BUTTON DOESN'T WORK
        //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Page3");

        //BACK BUTTON DOESN'T WORK
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page3(new ViewModel3()));
    }
}

Arrow pointing to the Back Button in the top left of page.

UPDATE:
Go to the flyout menu and select the Page 2.  If you go 2 pages deep from there you will experience the bug?

GITHUB:
I have added the project here.  See the readme.md
https://github.com/fatscally/Back-Button-Not-Working.git

The back button you're talking about is the one in the native navigation bar or a back button you're manually creating? Because from the comments in your code it seems that GoToPageX() is called pressing the back button.

@RiccardoMinato  I have added an image.  It is the default back arrow created on the page.  Also the Android Back button won't work.  And also Shell.Current.Navigation.PopModalAsync(); won't work.

You could try examining the NavigationStack and could get some hints.

I have added a link to the code in Github if anyone has time.   I'm wondering if this is a bug?  Or if somehow I'm breaking the navigation rules??

I can't run your code now, but looking at it I have some observations. You're registering routes in both App.xaml.cs and AppShell.xaml.cs. Then you're adding the pages as FlyoutItems in AppShell.xaml. You have to choose if a page is a FlyoutItem and in that case you don't need to register it explicitely, or if it's not and so you use Routing.RegisterRoute(), but only once. Consider that FlyoutItems are meant to be "root" pages, because you navigate to them using the flyout menu, so this could be the reason why your back button is not working.

Yes you are correct.  The duplicate in App.xaml.cs was an error by me in this test proj.
Other crazy observations: I've added 6 pages now.  The "bug" only happens when I start from page2 in the Flyout?!?

Flyout routing is not the same as Shell navigation hence your Back button issues. Mixing the navigation can lead to confusing Back button behavior.

The Route property in the Flyout seems to be the issue.  Hopefully somebody who knows a lot more about it will explain in the comments? ;)
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Page 1"
        Icon="one_icon.png"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OnePage}"
        ** Route="OnePage" />  <!-- << I believe this is the fault--> **
    <ShellContent
        Title="Page 2"
        Icon="two_icon.png"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TwoPage}"
        ** Route="TwoPage" />  <!-- << Delete this --> **
    <ShellContent
        Title="Page 3"
        Icon="three_icon.png"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ThreePage}"
        IsVisible="true"
        ** Route="ThreePage" /> <!-- << Delete this --> **

</FlyoutItem>


It's not necessarily Route fault. You're probably misusing it. You shouldn't navigate to pages defined as ShellContent like they were normal pages. They're meant to be navigated as flyout items.

Maybe I am doing it wrong?!  I just learn what I need to know and move on.  The code is there on GitHub if you want to play with it.  Thank for you help.

IMO the only thing you were doing wrong was the navigation. If you have a ShellContent page, let's say TwoPage, you shouldn't have something like Shell.Current.GoToAsync("TwoPage"), becauseTwoPage is an item shown from the flyout. So if you specify Route attributes in AppShell.xaml.cs for some pages, you register explicitely routes using Routing.RegisterRoute() for the other ones and you use Shell.Current.GoToAsync("PageName") only for pages which are not ShellContents, you should be ok.
